# On-click an image its move the image element, how to move the Div of the image with the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onclick

I have this JS script :

```
// JavaScript Document


var items_left = [];
var items_right = [];

function addTrade(left, object) {
        if(left === "true"){
            if(items_left.length < 4){


            items_left.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
            console.log(items_left.length);
            $(object).attr("onClick", "removeTrade(\"true\", this);");  

            $( "#addtrade_have" ).append($(object))




            }
        } else {

            if(items_right.length < 4){


            items_right.push($(object).attr("data-id"));
            console.log(items_right.length);
            $(object).attr("onClick", "removeTrade(\"false\", this);");

            $( "#addtrade_want" ).append($(object));

            }
        }
}

function submit() {

    console.log("Submit called!");

    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

    if(items_left.length > 0 && items_right.length > 0){

            var data_post = {comment: comment, h_1: items_left.shift(), h_2: items_left.shift(), h_3: items_left.shift(), h_4: items_left.shift(), w_1: items_right.shift(), w_2: items_right.shift(), w_3: items_right.shift(), w_4: items_right.shift()};

            console.log(data_post);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "trade_insert.php",
                data: data_post,
                success: function(){
                    alert("Trade sent!");
                    window.location.replace("mytrades.php");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("ERROR!");    
                }

            });

    } else {
        alert("You must add at least 1 item to each side!");    
    }
}
```

The PHP script :

```
<div id="addtrade_have"></div>
<div id="addtrade_want"></div>



                     <div class='skin'>
                  <div class='skin-item' data-id='".$item_id."'>
               <img onmouseover=\"nhpup.popup('<b>".$item_name." (".$exterior.")</b><br>".$rarity."');\" src='http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/".$icon_url."/99fx66f' alt='Picture not found!' class='img'  onClick=\"addTrade('true', this);\">
                    </div>  
                     </div>
```

And now the script do that when I click on the image, the image move to ID #addtrade_have but I have divs except  the image. how I can do that when I click on the image it will move the div and the image element I have?

thank you guys!

Comment: Can you create fiddle for your problem ?

Or just put down all your code to have a better understanding..

Comment: Post your HTML that is relevant to the problem. We can't keep guessing!

Comment: I edit my post with the html .. its not all of it. let me know if you need all the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try change :

```
$( "#addtrade_have" ).append($(object))
```

on

```
$( "#addtrade_have" ).append($(object).parent())
```

Look thru jQUery doc for [parent function](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

---

**Update**

The same way for

```
$( "#addtrade_want" ).append($(object));
```

change on

```
$( "#addtrade_want" ).append($(object).parent());
```

Or how many steps up you want - so many parents, or try use [closest() function](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) if you know ID or class of parent element